# Как заставить работать KDE plasma на wayland?

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde, wayland

У меня плазма 5.24 на арч. Еще с начала пользования(месяца полтора назад) плазма работает только на x11, на wayland она зависает намертво.
После обновления драйверов зависаний нет, теперь при попытке выбрать wayland на +-3 секунды гаснет экран и опять появляется окно входа. Как можно заставить ее работатть на wayland?
Готов предоставить все данные, что нужны

Comment: какой драйвер видео?

Comment: @eri используется nvidia, + доступен nouveau

Comment: KMS включен? (Параметр ядра `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`)

Comment: @andreymal а как это проверить?
Вот вывод lsmod:
```
|nvidia_drm             73728  13
nvidia_uvm           2744320  0
nvidia_modeset       1425408  27 nvidia_drm
nvidia              45367296  1698 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
```